# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Looooooooong HEAD requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've just deployed a simple Java/Tomcat based application into Elastic Beanstalk (using the java8/tomcat8 config). Mostly the application works fine.

However, all HEAD requests seem to take 60 seconds. Feels like a timeout of some kind. I can't seem to find any settings regarding filtering or delaying particular types of requests. These requests work fine when I run locally. GET requests to the same URL work fine.

I've confirmed that both the Tomcat and the Apache instance on the server log the HEAD request instantly (which indicates they are done with it, right?).

I've confirmed (using telnet) that the client is not receiving any response header bytes until very late.  This isn't a problem of the client waiting for a payload or something like that.

Furthermore, the delay is clearly tied to the load balancer's "Idle Timeout" setting. If I push that down to 5 seconds, then the HEAD requests take about 5 seconds, if I set the idle-timeout to 20 seconds then the HEAD requests take just about 20 seconds (always a few ms over).  The default is 60s.

What could be causing all HEAD requests (even those returning a 401 unauthorized error, no processing) to clog up the works like that?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was a firewall issue at the local site.  AWS ElasticBeanstock was returning the responses in a timely manner, but they were getting clogged up in a local firewall.  Grr..